# Reflection of a line through a plane: ball bouncing

Tags: linear-algebra

> In an orthonormal system, a ball is sent from a point $ P = (2, 6, 5) $ in such a direction that after it bounces on a plane π with the equation $ x - z = -2 $, it passes the point $ Q = (3, 3, 7) $. Specify the ball's direction after the bounce appropriately.

My idea was to reflect the ball's direction vector about the plane's normal $ n = (1, 0, -1) $, but this requires the computation of said direction vector and it would seem impossible to compute.

You could imagine a point $ Q' $ that would be on the opposite side of the plane, which would be the ball's position hadn't it bounced off of the plane -- but this requires another computation that I seem unable to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding $ Q' $ is possible, but not the easiest way. If we calculate it and get the direction vector of that line, we will still need to reflect it about the plane's normal.

Instead, consider that there is a point $ P' $ opposite in the same was as Q' is to Q.

We calculate it by stating that there must be a multiple of the plane's normal that extends to P, or $ P + λn \in π $. If so then $ P' = P + 2λn $. From this we find the reflected line's direction vector:

$$ P + λn \in π $$

$$ (2, 6, 5) + λ(1, 0, -1) = (z-2, y, z) $$

$$ \implies λ=1/2 $$
$$ \implies P' = (2, 6, 5) + (1, 0, -1) = (3, 6, 4) $$
$$ \implies v = Q - P' = (0, -3, 3) $$